# NoMethodError in SingleRequests#create - undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am stuck on this issue for quite a long time - any help would be appreciated!

I have a controller where I have updated the CRUD classes.

I have views for new, edit and show as well. Each of those calls a form which validates the presence of 2 of the 4 details in the form. I also have a a private class created for set_associate data (as shown in the controller pic).

I have called this in the new method. The form gets saved but I am unable to edit the form again. Also, if either one of the necessary fields are missing - I am getting the error:

> *NoMethodError in SingleRequests#create - undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass*

[image: The Controller with all the methods and the private class for set_associate]

The form (which is called in the new, show and edit views) is as follows - it also contains the validating error message portion (*the part which is not working and throwing the given error when the necessary fields are not filled*)

[image: Form which also contains the validation of components]

Comment: Add error backtrace in your question. If you can add concerned code in the question itself (instead of links to images) that would be great.

Comment: It's better to copy and paste the code into your question, and use the "{}" control to format it as code-text, than to include images.

Answer (score 0):

Your view is expecting `@associate_data` to be a hash, but on the new method it's just nil.

You can change your `set_associate` method to handle this.

```
def set_associate
  @associate_data = session[:associate] || {associate_id' => ''}
end
```

So if the session variable is not available you'll default to a hash with just 'associate_id' with an  empty string.

You could, in fact, do `@associate_data = session[:associate] || {}` but then you have to modify the view line...

```
...@associate_data['associate_id'][2..-1]
```

Into

```
...@associate_data['associate_id'].to_s[2..-1]
```

to handle the case of nil value in the key/value pair.

And don't forget that you may need to run `set_associate` in your `create` method in the event you have to re-render the `new` form.

```
else
  set_associate
  render :new
end
```

Comment: I am still facing issue - NoMethodError in SingleRequests#create

C:/Users/RB045667/Desktop/Software/Metrics-Assessment-Productivity-MAP/maps/app/views/single_requests/_form.html.erb where line #22 raised:
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass